# Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded

Tags: sql-server

`type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application'`. Are you missing an assembly reference?

```
 FileCopy("\\Thulller\Sistema\ModeloAbertaFechada.xls", "\\Thulller\Sistema\Financeiro\" + txtNomeDoc.Text + ".xls")
            Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
            Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
            Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
            xlApp = New Excel.Application
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\Thulller\Sistema\Financeiro\" + txtNomeDoc.Text + ".xls")
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Plan1")
```

Comment: Guilherme bem vindo ao  stackoverflow em português , faça um [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e traduza sua pergunta para que possa se analisada.

Comment: Guilherme faça o que o Marconcílio falou, caso contrario será negativado varias vezes e isso não é bom!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mensagem acima diz que está faltando uma **referência** a DLL "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application", tenha certeza de que adicionou uma referência a esta DLL em seu projeto. Por minha análise vi que está utilizando o **Microsoft Office Tools**, adicione a referência a DLL como no exemplo abaixo.
[image: Adicionar referência a DLL do Microsoft Office Tools]

Lembrando que esta **extensão** está disponível no **NET FRAMEWORK 4.0 Client Profile**.

Comment: Bom dia, desculpe não responder ontem, estive um pouco ocupado !

Tenho só a agradecer a ajuda mas peço paciência para a resolução pois sou leigo em programação ! 
Esses problemas estão dando em um programa em que um amigo meu criou e ele não esta mais podendo me dar o devido suporte então estou tendo que me virar sozinho !

Todas as config dele esta no Visual Studio 10 com um banco criado no access do microsoft office.